# The animation on window closing does not appear after SetWindowRgn

Tags: wpf, windows, winapi

I want to show a window with a custom region and a custom appearance. I hook a window proc and set the custom region on WM_SIZE message by SetWindowRgn function. Also i process a WM_NCCALCSIZE to remove standard window frame.

```
    [SecuritySafeCritical]
    protected virtual IntPtr HwndSourceHookHandler(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) {
        if(msg == WinApi.WM_NCCALCSIZE) {

            handled = true;
            return IntPtr.Zero;

        }
        if(msg == WinApi.WM_SIZE) {
            if(region != IntPtr.Zero)
                WinApi.DeleteObject(region);
            int width = lParam.ToInt32() & 0xFFFF;
            int height = lParam.ToInt32() >> 16;
            region = WinApi.CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, width, height, 40, 40);
            WinApi.SetWindowRgn(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle, region, true);
        }

        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
```

The window is appeared on my Windows 8.1 OS with a round corners as expected and without border and window buttons. But i notice that in this case window is closed immediately without performing the close animation. If i comment SetWindowRgn, all works fine. Anyone knows what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The animation is being performed in the `Window`. Therefore, you need to stop the `Window` from actually closing when the close `Button` is pressed and start the animation then instead. When the animation is complete, *then* you should close the `Window`. This can be achieved as follows:

Handle the `Window.Closing` and `Window.Close` events:

```
private void AnimationWindow_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (!isCloseAnimationComplete)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        CloseWindow();
    }
}

private void AnimationWindow_Close(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CloseWindow();
}

public void CloseWindow()
{
    // Set up animation
    animation.Completed += CloseAnimation_Completed;
    // Start animation
}

private void CloseAnimation_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    isCloseAnimationComplete = true;
    // Actually close Window here
    Close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But i need that the standard closing animation was performed, as it is performed without SetWindowRgn call.